# Apex Cpu Limit Exceeded Error in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, governorlimits, cpulimit

I have written trigger in salesforce code,it is already bulkified,But i am getting cpu limit exceeded error,while updating 200 records using Workbench

Trigger code:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before Update,after insert, after update) {
if(Trigger.IsUpdate){ 

            List<Summary__c> sumUpdatelst = [SELECT Id, Name, Account__c FROM Summary__c WHERE Account__c = : trigger.new];

            if(sumUpdatelst.isEmpty()){

                List<Summary__c> sumlst = new List<Summary__c>();

                for(Account acq : trigger.new){ 
                    sumlst.add(New Summary__c(Name = acq.Name, Account__c = acq.Id, Recordtype = acq.RecordType));
                }

                If(!sumlst.isEmpty()){
                    INSERT sumlst;
                } 
            } 
        }
    }

    If(Trigger.IsAfter){

        if(Trigger.IsInsert){

            List<Summary__c> sumlst = new List<Summary__c>();

            for(Account acq : trigger.new){

                sumlst.add(New Summary__c(Name = acq.Name, Account__c = acq.Id, Recordtype = acq.RecordType));
            }
            If(!sumlst.isEmpty()){
                INSERT sumlst;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error :

> "Id","Success","Created","Error"
>   "","false","false","CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY:objectTrigger:
>   System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded:--"
>   "","false","false","CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY:objectTrigger:
>   System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded:--"
>   "","false","false""","false","false","CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY:AccountTrigger:
>   System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded:--"
>   "","false","false","CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY:objectTrigger:
>   System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded:-

-

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74505/discussion-on-question-by-sfdc-developer-apex-cpu-limit-exceeded-error-in-trigge).

Comment: Is Summary__c object master-detail to Account object? Also is your processes update account in any way?

Comment: lookupRealtionship summary__c to Account object @tugce